# UIWebView Not getting positioned in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Hi I am making custom cells subcalling `UITableViewCell` class. In each cell I have a `UIWebView`. While initializing the cell I am trying to change position of the UIWebView using following code:

```
self.webview.center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
```

but the position is not changing. Do anyone has any idea why?

I am making this call in `layoutSubviews`. I am loading the cell from an xib and the final cell layout is unchangeable.

Comment: Nobody came across this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you init your webView with frame, like this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

Comment: So how about if you do this porgramaticaly and then add webView as subview to your cell:

Comment: I will check.. but can't we reposition the elements created by xibs?

Comment: Yes, but have more "power" when you set some things programaticaly than set them in xib. So check if it work and let me know.

Comment: With my implementation (with nib) i noticed one thing: if i select the row its getting positioned correctly (to my given coordinates)..

Comment: I tried according to your suggestion too.. but uiwebview did not show up.. I think i am doing something terribly wrong here..

Comment: I do this in this way and it's worked for me:     UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
    webView.center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [cell addSubview:webView];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18657/discussion-between-edzio27-and-user739711)

Comment: Thanks again.. it was very helpful.. I am wondering why repositioning with the xib object don't work..